# SQL insert data into a table from another table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm having a problem trying to insert some values into a table. I made an empty table with  the fields

```
id(primary key) 
association_id 
resource_id
```

I have another table with

```
resource_id
association_id
```

and another one with

```
id(coresponding to the association_id in the former one)
image
```

I want to insert the `resource_id` and `association_id` from the first populated table, where the image field of the coresponding id from the last table is not empty.

I tried this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `logo_associations` (``,`association_id`,`resource_id`)
SELECT 
        ``,
        `a`.`association_id`,
        `a`.`resource_id`
FROM doc24_associations_have_resources a
Join doc24_associations    An on a.association_id = An.id 
WHERE An.image<>''
```

but it does not work

Comment: What do you mean by 'empty', can they also be `NULL`? Then check for `WHERE An.image<>'' AND An.image IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: I think he mean that a row might and might not exist for each association in that table. That is a null checking with a left join

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: I ment that the image field might have the value, for example image.jpg or be empty

Comment: Can you show a few example lines from the affected tables (before/after query where applicable)?

Comment: I use MariaDB mysql server

Comment: I does not affect any row in the empty table, that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is based on SQL Server but the SQL may be very similar

```
 INSERT INTO DestinationTable
        (association_id, resource_id)
 SELECT LNK.assocication_id,
        LNK.resource_id
   FROM LinkTable AS LNK
        INNER JOIN ImageTable AS IMG ON IMG.id = LNK.association_id
                   AND IMG.image IS NOT NULL
```

Above I assume the following:

1. Tables are named DestinationTable, LinkTable, and ImageTable respectively
2. In DestinationTable the primary key (id) is auto generated

Comment: 14:12:35 INSERT INTO doc24.logo_associations         (association_id, resource_id)  SELECT LNK.assocication_id,         LNK.resource_id    FROM doc24.doc24_associations_have_resources AS LNK         INNER JOIN doc24.doc24_associations AS IMG ON IMG.id = LNK.association_id                    AND IMG.image IS NOT NULL Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'LNK.assocication_id' in 'field list' 0.000 sec

Comment: that was a misspelled word but now I get, duplicate entry 0 for primary key

Comment: it adds 0 for all ids that it's why it's crashing... do you know how to make i give different ids?

Comment: changed the primary key to auto increment and put <>'' instead of IS NOT NULL and worked like charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO logo_associations (association_id, resource_id)
SELECT a.association_id
      ,a.resource_id
FROM doc24_associations_have_resources a
LEFT JOIN doc24_associations an ON a.association_id = an.id 
WHERE an.image IS NULL -- check for null with left join
```

This is valid for SQL Server. You do not need to select and insert the first column as it is an identity as you mention.

Comment: I've runned the script on mysql workbench but the table still remains empty

Comment: I am not sure if the statement is valid for MySQL, but in case it is then you probably have no valid association ids in that table